# Engineering Equation Solver (EES) Entropy returning NEGATIVE numbers

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, software

I am using [Engineering Equation Solver](http://www.fchart.com/ees/) (EES).

When I try to find Entropy given Temperature and Quality (liquid) at saturation pressure for carbon dioxide I keep getting a negative number.

> s=Entropy('CarbonDioxide',T=300[K],x=0)

I had hoped this was posted as a known problem... then the thought struck me that it might be isolated to just me after an extensive search.

Would someone give this script a try on their computer and tell me if they are getting the same results, or better yet point out what wall I have hit my head into and point out to me the obvious cause that I am blind to. :)

Note:
This is regarding the finding of Entropy at a specific state in a steady-state system, NOT the change in Entropy which can be negative.

Script:

```
$UnitSystem SI K Pa kJ mass deg
$TabStops 0.2 3.5 in
R$='CarbonDioxide'
T=300 [K]
s_l=Entropy(R$,T=T,x=0)   "find Entropy for liquid"
s_v=Entropy(R$,T=T,x=1)   "find Entropy for vapour"
h_l=Enthalpy(R$,T=T,x=0)   "find Enthalpy for liquid"
```

Solution Window:

```
h_l=-223.9 [kJ/kg]
R$='CarbonDioxide'
s_l=-1.465 [kJ/kg-K] <------ NEGATIVE ?!? how is this posible?
s_v=-1.117 [kJ/kg-K] <------ NEGATIVE ?!? how is this posible?
T=300 [K]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it is about debugging software. “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Comment: I'm not familiar with this software, but I would say that likely your "Entropy" function is actually giving you an entropy _change_, presumably from some "standard" conditions (e.g. pressure 100 kPa, 20 degrees C or 1 atm and 0 degrees C, etc.) - not absolute entropy, down to the solidus or liquidus. While this question has been closed as off-topic, it would be a very much _on_-topic question to ask about the physics behind _why_ that entropy changes are often considered much more than "absolute" entropies, though it probably has been asked already.

Comment: The manual with the software should tell you this - though sadly far too many manuals are not written very well and some even though they should be written with quality prose imo. Nonetheless even for the raggy and often far too unhelpful standards that prevail in this area, I'd _hope_ they would not leave out such a basic and crucial detail.

Comment: Anyone who knows anything about thermodynamics realizes that this is not an off-topic engineering question.  It is a question about whether a certain piece of thermodynamics software correctly delivers  the entropy of saturated carbon dioxide at prescribed temperature and mass fraction vapor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably expressed relative to a specified reference state where s is taken as zero.  Check the EES literature for what this reference state is.

Comment: I am using Temperature and Quality (0 - 1) as the reference state variables.  The error seems to only come up when using Quality (x).  What has me confused is the above script works on other substances (ie: 'R134a) but fails when 'CarbonDioxide' is used.  @ChetMiller

Comment: The entropy change for vaporization looks correct.  What you are calling a "reference state" is not the same thing I was referring to.  There is some state specified by a combination of temperature and pressure that they are using as the state of zero entropy.  It is probably 298 K and 1 bar.